# Label control in ASP.NET failure to pick a Label property

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am trying to use the Label control of ASP.NET as below:

```
public static bool addData(string storedProcName, string[] dynamicParamName, object[]    paramVals, Label msg)
{
    msg = "Recorded Added successfully";
    cmd2.Connection.Close();
    cmd2.Dispose();        
}
```

However, I do not seem to get the "Text" property of Labels, as in msg.Text. Is there something I am missing here? Thank you.

Comment: What are you referencing in your code file?

Comment: Add more details, how do you instantiate your Label control, what is msg? A string or your label control? What do you mean by "do not get the "Text" property of Label?

Comment: I create it below as part of arguements:

   public static bool addData(string storedProcName,string []    dynamicParamName,Object[] paramVals,Label msg){

Then I try to use it as below:

                              msg=new Label();
                             msg = "Recorded Added successfully";

But the "msg.Text"  property is failing to come up. I would like to post the whole code but it shows up mixed up on this page. Thank you

Comment: u just edit your own question and post the full code.

Comment: @Jim: there is a button when editing to mark things as code. In practice this puts four spaces at the beginning of each line. Or if worst comes to worst paste it in mixed up and put in an appeal for somebody else to edit it for you. :)

Comment: @thevan- Please help I cant see the button for marking this as code!

public static bool res=false;

   public static bool addData(Label lb){
     
        lb=new Label();
    
        lb.Text="Welcome Home";

       res=true;

       return res;


    }

This is the simple code am trying. I am trying this in a Class. But the lb.Text property is not coming up. Does this not work in a class or what am I missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much as Chris Mullins suggested it looks like you are referring to the wrong type of label.

I am surprised that you aren't getting any comments of ambiguous names if you definitely have the System.Web.UI.WebControls referenced in a using statement. However, you should be able to fix it by either removing the line that you probably have saying "`Using System.Windows.Controls`" or by changing your reference to lable to be:

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lb = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label();
```

Or similar things.

Essentially it all looks like it boils down to ambiguity of the label class in your code.

Comment: Thank you very very much... It might have been refering to wrong reference. This has worked now as you have suggested!. Cheers !

Comment: Cool. I was only really expanding on what other Chris had started but wanted to say more than would fit in a comment. Don't forget to click on the tickbox next to his answer to mark it as accepted (since I think his is now more comprehensive than mine.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you have **using System.Web.UI.WebControls;** in your using section.  Other than that you probably have a syntax error somewhere causing .net to not give you the intellisense.

Based on what you said in your comment it sounds like you may be working in a class library, if so make sure you include a reference to **System.Web**  If you have a reference to **System.Windows.Forms** or a **using System.Windows.Forms**, you can remove them if you are not using them.

If you include both **using System.Windows.Forms** and **using System.Windows.Forms** then the compiler may not know which one you mean when you just say Label, in which case you would have to fully qualify it with all the namespaces.

Comment: Dear Chris, O do have it, but the intellisense will not just show. When I try the same in the code for the form, it works, but when I try this in my user defined class in a method, it fails. I have all the required libs in the using section. What else can I show u to help?

Comment: If you change it to msg.Text = "Recorded Added successfully", and you try to compile the project do you get any errors?

Comment: If I ignore and compile, It says System.Windows.Control.Label does not contain a definition for "Text" and no extension method.

Comment: I updated my answer, it sounds like you are referencing the wrong type of label, like the other Chris says, and also possibly missing the reference to System.Web

Comment: Thanks Chris...I was refering to wrong refenrence. Many thanks indeed

Comment: @Chris Mullins: brief typo correction - you have system.windows.forms twice in your last paragraph.